# How to prove a odd number is the successor of double of nat in coq?

Tags: coq

I have the odd number definition as below:

```
Definition Odd n := exists k, n = 2*k+1.
```

And I have an oddb define that whether a number is odd or not.

```
Fixpoint oddb (n : nat) { struct n } : bool :=

match n with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => true
  | S (S n) => oddb n
  end.
```

I am trying to prove if a number is the successor of a double of nat; then it is a odd number.

```
Theorem question_1c:
  forall n, Odd n -> (oddb n = true).
Proof.
  unfold Odd. intros. inversion H. 
  rewrite H0. simpl. induction x. 
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - Admitted.
```

I stuck on the second goal.. it showed that I need to prove Sx.. and the hypothesis I have from now seems like not helpful...

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
H : exists k : nat, n = 2 * k + 1
x : nat
H0 : n = 2 * S x + 1
IHx : n = 2 * x + 1 -> oddb (x + (x + 0) + 1) = true
______________________________________(1/1)
oddb (S x + (S x + 0) + 1) = true
```

Can anyone help me?? tHnak you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard induction let you jump from `n` to `n+1`. Here with your `odd` function
you need to jump from `n` to `n+2`. So what is needed is a stronger induction. One way to do this is to prove:

```
Theorem question_1c:
  forall n m, m <= n -> Odd m -> (oddb m = true).
```

by standard induction on `n` (but for all `m` smaller)