# Is it possible to prove oddb 0 = true?? coq

Tags: coq

I have define an odd like this:

```
 Inductive odd : nat -> Prop :=
  | odd_1 : odd 1
  | odd_S : forall n:nat, odd n -> odd (n + 1).
```

And below is testing if a number is odd or not.

```
Fixpoint oddb (n : nat) { struct n } : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => true
  | S (S n) => oddb n
  end.
```

I am trying to prove this:

```
Theorem odd_is_odd:
  forall n, (oddb n = true) -> odd n.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n.
  - simpl. intro H. exfalso. inversion H.
  - intro H. rewrite s_is_plus_one. constructor. apply IHn. destruct n.
    *
```

But i got stuck here... it needs me prove oddb 0 = true which is false = true.. is it possible???

```
1 subgoal
IHn : oddb 0 = true -> odd 0
H : oddb 1 = true
______________________________________(1/1)
oddb 0 = true
```

Below is the lemma I used

```
Lemma s_is_plus_one : forall n:nat, S n = n + 1.
Proof.
intros. induction n.
 - reflexivity.
 - simpl. rewrite <- IHn. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `odd` seems wrong. Is it not `n+2`. Anyway our problem
is related to
[How to prove a odd number is the successor of double of nat in coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67340256/how-to-prove-a-odd-number-is-the-successor-of-double-of-nat-in-coq/67341223#67341223)

Comment: Could you tell me how can I make the define the odd number inductively? The link you sent, I defined it direct using definition. However, I have to define it inductively. Thx

Comment: For defining inductively you first need to be sure that each line is ok, so

Comment: ```odd_1 : odd 1```

one is odd, fine.

```odd_S : forall n:nat, odd n -> odd (n + 1)```

if `n` is odd, then `n+1` : wrong.

3 is odd and 4 is not odd.

```odd_SS : forall n:nat, odd n -> odd (n + 2)```

much better!

Now are these two rules sufficient. Let suppose 
I want to prove that 11 is odd. How can I do.
`odd _1` tells me that 1 is odd. Applying 
```odd_SS tells me 3 is odd. Applying it again, 5, 7, 9
and finally 11. So using `odd_1` and `odd_SS` I can reach.
all the odd numbers. There are sufficent.